# PHP opens only index file, says others don't not exist, even though they do

Tags: php, .htaccess, include

So, I am making a website and I am putting it together with includes in index.php file.
The problem is that website opens and shows first page perfectly, but none of the languages links work!
Here is my code:

**Index file**:

```
<?php
    $languages = array("eng","lat");
    $sections = array("home");
    $sectionTitles = array("eng" =>array(
    "WHERE CAN YOU FIND US?",
    "WHO ARE WE?",
    "CONTACTS",
    ), 
        "lat"=>array(
                "KUR MŪS ATRAST?",
            "PAR MUMS",
            "KONTAKTI",
            ));

$lang = "lat";
$section = "home";

$content = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (!empty($content[1]) && (in_array($content[1], $languages))) { $lang = $content[1];}
if (!empty($content[2]) && (in_array($content[2], $sections))) { $section = $content[2];}
$sectionTitles = $sectionTitles[$lang];

include ("header.php");
include ("$lang/$section.php");
include ("footer.php");

?>
```

**.htaccess file**:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|ico)$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

link in my **header file**:

```
    <a href="/eng/<?=$section?>">eng</a>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does print_r($content) say?

Comment: Array ( [0] => [1] => )

So, how do i fix this? :(

Comment: OK, that means either $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is empty, then you have some configuration problem with your web server, or it contains something unexpected.

Comment: When I change link to <a href="/eng/home">ENG</a> it says that that file does not exist even thougn it does.

Comment: Thank you, @colburton, will contact my server guy.

Comment: Call /eng/home and tell us what's in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: The requested URL /eng/home was not found on this server.

Comment: Since PHP natively doesn't understand url rewrite, when you access `/eng/home`, it change it's Directory to `/docroot/eng/home` and then try to include /eng/home.php, which is indeed incorrect, you need to use `chdir` to set it to doc_root, you can check current folder using `getcd`

Answer (score 2):

Change htaccess file to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|ico)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /index.php?_url=$1 [L]
```

Then you can use

```
$content = explode("/", $_GET['_url']);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, will show this to my server guy.